# Detecting whether I can capture arrow keys via stdin

Tags: c++, emacs, posix, tty

I am trying to create a basic REPL. If my program is run in a terminal that can support it, I use the [termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) `getchar` to read input character-by-character and respond to special keys, such as the arrow keys. However, if run in a terminal for which that does not make sense, I'd like to switch to good old-fashioned `cin.getline`.

The trouble is in detecting whether the terminal has the capabilities I'm looking for. Initially, I was thinking `isatty` would do the trick.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  bool tty = isatty(fileno(stdin));
  std::cout << "You are using a TTY: " << std::boolalpha << tty << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This will correctly identify cases where stdin is a pipe or something like that. However, if I'm running a subshell inside Emacs (`M-x shell`, specifically), it still identifies as  a TTY, even though Emacs captures arrow keys and other special characters and does its own thing with them. What C++ or POSIX functionality can I use that would correctly distinguish between a subshell being run within Emacs and a shell being run with full control inside an "ordinary" terminal?

I'm primarily looking for POSIX solutions here, but Windows-only answers are useful for posterity as well.

---

*Footnote: Yes, I am aware of things like ncurses that handle all of this for me. I would like to do this without using such libraries, to improve my understanding of the terminal environment.*

Answer (score 1):

This is the purpose of the [`TERM` environment variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03).  You use (low-level) libraries like [terminfo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) to understand (the implications of) the value of `TERM`, although recognizing Emacs’ value of “dumb” is easy enough.